# Permissions error when trying to connect GCP SQL Database with Golang cloud sql proxy package

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to connect my go app on my VM (Debain 9) server to my mysql database using the package: `github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/proxy/dialers/mysql`

Looking at connection function:

```
 // Cfg returns the effective *mysql.Config to represent connectivity to the
// provided instance via the given user and password. The config can be
// modified and passed to DialCfg to connect. If you don't modify the returned
// config before dialing, consider using Dial or DialPassword.
func Cfg(instance, user, password string) *mysql.Config {
```

I assume I put in the instance 'Instance connection name that is found on the GCP instance connection database page: 
`
    package main

```
import (
"fmt"
"os"

"github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/proxy/dialers/mysql"
)

func main() {
    cfg := mysql.Cfg("MyAccount:us-west2:myDatabase", "root", os.Getenv("GCPDBPass"))
    db, err := mysql.DialCfg(cfg)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Print(db)
}
```

[Where I find my instance connection name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8bep.png)

I get an error:
`panic: ensure that the account has access to "MyAccount" (and make sure there's no typo in that name)`

I've hooked up the VM instance IP to the Authorized networks in the Database so I don't know if I'm using the correct instance or user with this package.

Comment: Please show the actual code that you are using and not one line. You are using the correct package and instance name format. Check that the service account for your instance has permissions to access Cloud SQL (Cloud SQL Client, Editor or Admin). Remove what you did with the IP in authorized networks as that is not used by Cloud SQL Proxy. Proxy uses service account roles to authorize access to Cloud SQL. You will of course need the correct login and password for the database.

Comment: Are you setting the environment variable needed to use a service account credentials? https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
Or do you need to add the `cloudSql.client` role to the VM's service account?

Also, when using the proxy, you shouldn't need to add the VM to the authorized networks

Comment: @JohnHanley

`package main

import (
 "fmt"
 "os"

 "github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/proxy/dialers/mysql"
)

func main() {
 cfg := mysql.Cfg("MyAccount:us-west2:myDatabase", "root", os.Getenv("dbPass"))
 db, err := mysql.DialCfg(cfg)
 if err != nil {
  panic(err)
 }
 fmt.Print(db)
}`

I'm unsure what you're asking with the permissions, also don't I need to set the Authorized networks for shell access to my DB?

@JacobLambert I don't believe this package uses the credentials json, I might need to add the cloudsql.client. I'm able to ssh in to make my dbs.

Comment: Compute Engine has a service account. Your code uses that service account. You need roles as I mentioned in order to use Cloud SQL Proxy. Note Edit your question with your code and not in comments which are hard to read.

Comment: After your edit. The Compute Engine Service Account does not have roles enabled for Cloud SQL. Go to the Google Cloud Console. Select your VM instance. Shutdown the instance. Edit the service account and enable Cloud SQL.

Comment: Thank you guys very much that solved my issue!

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was because of the lower version of the `"github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/proxy/dialers/mysql"` package. Upgrading the package using the command `go get -v -u github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy` resolved the issue. Below is the code snippet

```
"database/sql"
_ "github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/proxy/dialers/mysql"

connString := "user:password@cloudsql(project_id:region:instance)/dbname?charset=utf8&parseTime=True&loc=Local"
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", connectionString)
```